# jQuery Ajax success callback not firing nor returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have the follow POST request that isn't firing the success function nor is it giving me an error:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/me',
        data: {
            z_num: $("#selectEmployee").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('done post')
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

I know for a fact the request works because it sends `z_num` to the server for a database update (the database actually does get updated) so I'm not sure why it's not firing the success function... anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What kind of data are you returning from the server?

Comment: I'm not returning anything from the server. I'm only sending data from the client to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under some circumstances your server might not return the response correctly. Have you tried to handle the actual response code (e.g. if your server returns 200) like this:

```
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST', 
         url : '/api/me',
         data: { z_num: $("#selectEmployee").val()},
         statusCode: {
               200: function (response) {
                      // do your stuff here
                    }
         }
 });
```

Comment: Good point - I just tried your suggestion. I checked my console/network for the status of the request and it says 'pending'... and the response is also empty

Comment: note - i just added a response from my server so this works now. thank you!!